# Count number of rows in multiple Excel sheets and return values to a "summary" sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with 10 plus sheets.

On the "Summary" sheet I want to summarise how many rows are used on each of the other sheets.

I'm thinking that a Function that gets called multiple times is the most efficient.

If this is so, then I think it starts something like;

```
Function CountMyRows(SName)  # where SName is the name of a sheet
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    rowCount = Worksheets("SName").Rows.Count
```

Am I starting in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following two Functions into a module in the Workbook where you want to count the used rows in all worksheets. I used Function 'Test_it' to grab every sheet in the workbook, then call 'CountMyRows' by passing a Sheet name. To test it, place the cursor inside the 'Test_It' function, then press F5. You will see the results in the immediate window.

Note your code had to be changed because (1) it counted total rows in sheet - not used rows; and (2) an Integer may be too small ...

```
Function Test_It()
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Debug.Print Sheet.Name & vbTab & CountMyRows(Sheet.Name)
    Next Sheet
End Function


Function CountMyRows(SName) As Long         '# where SName is the name of a sheet
    Dim rowCount As Long
    rowCount = Worksheets(SName).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    CountMyRows = rowCount
End Function
```

Comment: thanks Wayne, didn't realise that it would count total rows :-( When I insert "=Test_It()" no quotes, I get #NAME - the formula contains unrecognized text. I realise its most likely just my novice approach...

Comment: so now that I have in in a module for the correct workbook ... I get a "0" returned. If I insert the name of a sheet into the 2nd funtion, I get the correct value (after deducting 1 for the Header). So it looks like the name of the tab is not being passed to teh second function, is that correct?

Comment: I updated the answer, but if you want to use this in existing code, you just need to call 'CountMyRows' passing a sheet name and receiving the # rows. i.e. MsgBox "Rows in Sheet1 = " & CountMyRows("Sheet1").

Comment: thanks Wayne, I'll chk it out on Monday. An excellent and quick response :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to summarise how many rows are used on each of the other sheets

you're looking for [UsedRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange.aspx) property:

```
Function CountMyRows(SName As String) As Long
    CountMyRows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SName).UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Function
```

note, that I'm using `Worksheets(SName)` without quotes and also it's more reliable to use `Long` type for storing rows count, because max value of `Integer` is only `32767`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

List Your sheets (names) in `A1-Axx`, in column B (e.g. cell `B1`) enter a formula:

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT(A1&"!A:A"))
```

In example below I added "-1" to not to count header row in sheets.

---

[image: 1]