# Trying to print the values of all the total number rows from multiple sheets into a column in a results page

Tags: vba, excel

another problem... Its driving me nuts!! (I am still very new to vba)

I am trying to count all the rows from multiple sheets into one results page. This is what I have:

```
Sub CallerSub()
    Worksheets("Testing").Column(1).Select.Value = Test_It

End Sub

Function Test_It()
For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.sheets
    Debug.Print sheet.name & vbTab & CountMyRows(sheet.name)
Next sheet
End Function


Function CountMyRows(SName) As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long
rowCount = Worksheets(SName).UsedRange.Rows.Count

End Function
```

The error that is coming up is 'Object does not support this property or method'

Code is mostly from:

[Count number of rows in multiple Excel sheets and return values to a "summary" sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694463/count-number-of-rows-in-multiple-excel-sheets-and-return-values-to-a-summary-s)

Edit: Error is on this line: 
    Worksheets("Testing").Column(1).Select.Value = Test_It

Thank you

Comment: `CountMyRows` does not return so is 0, `CountMyRows = Worksheets(SName).UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: Oh okay! But the error is still coming up! See my edit

Comment: What line is the error happening on? CallerSub wont work as test_it doesn't return either,

Comment: Worksheets("Testing").Column(1).Select.Value = Test_It @Nathan_Sav 
This is in the Caller sub

Comment: `Test_it` needs to return a variant array for what you are trying to achieve or single values looped.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Sorry, what does that mean?

Comment: Look it up, give it more than a minute, and you'll understand what you are trying to do.  Function returns, arrays, a range is an array at the bottom line.  Range("a1:a10").value is an array of 10 elements of data.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thanks for you help! Will have a look

Answer (score 0):

`CountMyRows` does not return so is 0, `CountMyRows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SName).UsedRange.Rows.Count` will make your function return a value.

```
Sub CallerSub()

    Dim a() As Variant
    a = Test_It

    Worksheets("Testing").Range("a1").Resize(UBound(a) + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(a)

End Sub

Function Test_It() As Variant()

Dim a() As Variant

On Error GoTo eHandle

For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) + 1)
    a(UBound(a)) = Sheet.Name & vbTab & CountMyRows(Sheet.Name)
Next Sheet

Test_It = a

Exit Function

eHandle:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        ReDim a(0)
        Resume Next
    End If

End Function

Function CountMyRows(SName) As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long
    CountMyRows = Worksheets(SName).UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach to your set-up, but if all you need is a column containing the count for each tab..

```
Sub CallerSub()
    Dim rw As Long
    rw = 0

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        rw = rw + 1
        Cells(rw, 1) = CountMyRows(sht.Name)
    Next
End Sub


Function CountMyRows(SName As String) As Long
    CountMyRows = Sheets(SName).UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Function
```

Note: This counting process WILL include the sheet that the output is being written to - and as it counts *before* it writes, it may not be correct. You could exclude a certain sheet with an IF statement..